# Can you add a build step for github pages deployment?

Tags: angular, deployment, continuous-integration, travis-ci, github-pages

I would like to use the master branch of my repo as the source for my github page. I need a build step (`ng build --prod --aot`) to generate the `index.html` file that would need to be displayed. I also don't want the generated files to be versionned. Is there a way to accomplish that using Github alone or with Travis CI or any other tool?

Comment: What is ng? Please add a tag for ng to your question.

Comment: `ng` is the CLI for angular project

Comment: OK, I've just realised that your requirements don't make sense. GitHub pages stores your pages in a versioned branch. So it doesn't make sense to use GitHub pages without versioning. The whole point is they are versioned.

Comment: Of course I want my code to be versioned, just not the generated files. `ng build --prod --aot` generates the .html that is needed. For example, if you deploy your code on Heroku, you can add a build step for generating files. Me saying that I don't want my generated files to versionned is like saying I don't want my node_modules to be versioned..that's the way it's supposed to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add a step to the build process on the github side. The process that takes your repository and turns it into something servable can only be controlled by the setting on the profile page.

In the end, if the index file is not jekyll, it will be served as is from the repository.

The one thing you can do is have two repositories - one of the "source" and one that is the actual pages that are served. That at least will keep the index.html file out of the source repository.

Comment: Right, I ended up only versionning the files in a gh-pages branch.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the [travis deployment system](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/pages/) to github pages is exactly what you need:

> Deploying to GitHub Pages uses `git push --force` to overwrite the history on the target branch, so make sure you only deploy to a branch used for that specific purpose, such as `gh-pages`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Deploy To Github Pages to configure a build step before publishing to your Github Pages:

https://github.com/marketplace/actions/deploy-to-github-pages

Basically: you have to configure your project to with github pages, served from the `gh-pages` branch. Next, you configure a Github Action to perform the build and deploy step using Deploy To Github Pages as described in the docs of the tool.